# Android Room: Order By not working

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using the new Android ORM Room. 
And I faced the following issue, queries that use ORDER BY with arguments don't work.

If I want to use the field populated from a parameter for ORDER BY it does not work. It just doesn't sort anything.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY :orderBY ASC")
List<User> sortedFind(String orderBY);
```

But, when I put the ORDER BY column directly in the query to sort the results, then it works as expected.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY name ASC")
List<User> sortedFind();
```

Is it a bug on Android Room, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: reported to google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62169706

Comment: My guess is that they are not expecting that piece of the query to be variable. AFAIK, SQLite would not support `SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY ? ASC` either, if you used it directly without Room.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah. It's make sense.. Thanks for replying.

Comment: In order to avoid writing multiple queries, that would be a great feature to have in Room.

Answer (score 14):

**What is happening**

The only values you can pass as paramters to `@Dao` methods are values, not query strings.  The reason for this (I beleive) is to prevent SQL injection issues.

**Why this is the case**

For example the query `SELECT * emails WHERE uid = ?` then setting the value as `"1 OR WHERE isAdmin = true"`. This would allow people to run their own bespoke queries on your database and do what they want.

**My Solution**

I ran into this problem as well. Here is a link to my [solution](https://github.com/jackfrancisdalton/LiteratureAnalyser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jackfrancisdalton/com/LiteratureAnalyser/service/RunTimeGeneratedQueryService.java).

My solution has 2 parts. First `DynamicQueryservice` that generates the query string and value array based on input, then runs the raw query and returns a `Cursor`. Second, a `Cursor2POJO` mapper so I do not have to write out cursor mappings over and over for classes, nor introduce potential maintenance issues. I just add annotations to my classes (that match up with room column names) and the lib handles the rest.

I've separated my Cursor mapper into its own [library](https://github.com/jackfrancisdalton/Cursor2POJO) for your benefit, feel free to use it (just made it so if the readme is not clear, or there are bugs hit me up in the comments).

P.S. My library cannot use Room @ColumnInfo to get column names as the annotation is currently set as RetentionPolicy.CLASS so cannot be accessed through reflection. (added to Google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63720940)

Comment: The reason you cannot pass query strings is more likely that we would then lose compile-time safety of our queries - a fundamental benefit of Room.

Comment: Not allowing a parameter to be used for the ORDER BY for security purposes sounds totally lame.

Answer (score 14):

If you are trying order by on string field then you may face string upper and lower case issue,
Then you should try with **LOWER(your_string_field_name)** or **UPPER(your_string_field_name)**
Like below:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY LOWER(name) ASC"
```

Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 12):

You should use `@RawQuery` annotation and `SupportSQLiteQuery` class for runtime query

In Dao:

```
 @RawQuery
 List<Objects> runtimeQuery(SupportSQLiteQuery sortQuery);
```

To get data:

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY " + targetField + " ASC";
List<Objects> users = appDatabase.daoUser().runtimeQuery(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(query));
```

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem

That's not the right way to pass the `ORDER BY`-column, Because the Room Database does not recognize it.

Any passing `String` data to the `@Query` Statment, `RoomDB` going to add  Single Quotation Marks to it, So for example in your code:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY :orderBY ASC")
List<User> sortedFind(String orderBY);
```

when you call the `sortedFind` function:

```
sortedFind("UserId");
```

The query for RoomDB going to be like `SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY 'UserId' ASC`, So the problem here **'UserId'** is not a column.

### The Right Way to do this

By using the **SQLite CASE** To check the Column Name and set the `ORDER BY`-column By that Column, like the Following:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User "+
        " ORDER BY  "+
        "      CASE :orderBY WHEN 'UserId' THEN UserId END DESC," +
        "      CASE :orderBY WHEN 'UserName' THEN UserName END DESC," +
        "      CASE :orderBY WHEN 'UserAge' THEN UserAge END DESC" )
List<User> sortedFind(String orderBY);
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked, but you have to be careful to put the when variable in quotes and not use the actual variable here. That tripped me up for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

you can only arrange data in ascending order in reference to name of any of column.
Programatically you cannot pass any value to Dao methods