# How to pass Order By param to Room @Query?

Tags: android, android-room

I have something like this in my Dao:

```
@Query("select * from orders ORDER BY time desc")
fun getAllOrders(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Order>
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
@Query("select * from orders ORDER BY :order :orderDirection")
fun getAllOrders(order:String, orderDirection:String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Order>
```

Any idea how to accomplish that? Compiler says:

> Error:(9, 1) error: extraneous input ':orderDirection' expecting {, ';', ',', '=', '*', '+', '-', '||', '/', '%', '<<', '>>', '&', '|', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!=', '<>', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_AND, K_ASC, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_BETWEEN, K_COLLATE, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DESC, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_GLOB, K_IN, K_INSERT, K_IS, K_ISNULL, K_LIKE, K_LIMIT, K_MATCH, K_NOT, K_NOTNULL, K_OR, K_PRAGMA, K_REGEXP, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

I have also tried this: (passing '`time desc`' as param) but `Room` ignored it.

```
@Query("select * from orders ORDER BY :order")
fun getAllOrders(order:String): DataSource.Factory<Int, Order>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are u not able to do like this    @Query("SELECT * FROM general_notifications ORDER BY :orderByColumnAndOrder")
    abstract Flowable<List<GeneralNotificationModel>> getAllNotifications(String orderByColumnAndOrder);  Where orderByColumnAndOrder i will pass "received_time DESC" as string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room: Order By not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240906/android-room-order-by-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

**It is a Syntax error in your SQL Query.**

Make sure that when you are forming your Query,put a space at the end of each line.

**Try this type of query for passing params**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + "UGC"
            + " WHERE "
            + UGC_USER_ID + "=" + ":userID"
            + " AND "
            + UGC_ID + "=" + ":id"
            + ";")
          fun getUgcData(userID:Integer,id:Integer):List<Ugc>
```