# Sort by order in Query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room as ORM. I want to get array of some objects from it with a specific order. My code looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE id IN (:ids) ORDER BY id in (:ids)")
```

But "order by" does not work. I don't want just to sort it by field "id". I want to sort it by id that correlate with array "ids". I mean:

I have array of Integer `ids = arrayOf(16,12,18,3)` and I use it in query above. And on the output, I want to have array of some object(say group). The output array will look like this:

```
    ListOf(Group(id:16, name: "someName"),
           Group(id: 12, name: "someAnotherName",
           Group(id: 18, name: "name"), 
           Group(id: 3, name: "another"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240906/android-room-order-by-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room: Order By not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240906/android-room-order-by-not-working)

Comment: @NileshRathod, my question is not the same question which in the link.

Comment: @VicJordan, my question is not the same question which in the link.

Comment: actually it's better to provide sample data and expected results

Comment: to sort data in such a way you have to create temp table in the database and populate it with ids and corresponding array indexes(so it's a bit tricky). better to extract data without ordering, create custom comparator and sort the data in Kotlin

Comment: @oreh, i corrected my answer. Actually, a little time ago i solved it. But i don't like my way:  @Query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE id IN (:ids) ORDER BY id = 16 DESC, id = 11 DESC, id = 10 DESC, id = 82 DESC, id = 19")

Comment: I've posted an aswer which will help to eliminate hardcoded sort order

Comment: @oreh, i don't like the way in your answer because it has 2 cycle. Ideally if it will in query(even if it will hard code, because my case allow it). But if nobody will not give answer, then i will check your answer as correct.

Comment: I was working with Oracle database for a long time and still cannot understand how your query actually returns correct result)

Comment: @oreh, kotlin magic)

Answer (score 2):

So you where quite close. Try using

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE id IN (:ids) ORDER BY id")
```

That should work for you. Im not sure on the `group`

Comment: this work. But works not as i want. It sort in ASC. I want sort array by specific position. (Like elements in array "ids")

Answer (score 1):

You using wrong way, `ORDER BY id in (:ids)` is incorrect

it should be

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE id IN (:ids) ORDER BY id")
```

Comment: this work. But works not as i want. It sort in ASC. I want sort array by specific position. (Like elements in array "ids")

Comment: so I think you should create a method in java/kotlin code to do it

Comment: for me, it's impossible (with you condition), and one point more, i think you should update your question, clearly, as you said me, its will help another people can give a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from database in the order you want is impossible, as the database don't know about current indexes in the array for ids. Actually it's possible, but you have to provide this information in a query or store it beforehand in a table.

What you actually want, is to get corresponding group information by some ids, so

- retrieve group data without ordering

  ```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM group WHERE id IN (:ids)")
  fun getGroupsById(): List<Group>`
  ```
- store the result into a `map`

  ```
  val idToGroups = mapOf<Long, Group>()
  for (group in getGroupsById()) {
      idToGroups[group.id] = group
  }
  ```
- then while iterating over initial `ids` array, get corresponding groups by `id`

  ```
  for (id in ids) {
      // here group is related to each position in the array
      group = idToGroups[id]
      println("Id: ${id}, Name: ${group.name}")
  }
  ```