# Room (Kotlin, Android) Query with String variable

Tags: android, kotlin

Question is:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY :myString DESC")
fun getMyString(myString: String): List<X>
```

Doesn't deliver the results upon giving "apple" string into function above. Althought if the query will be without variable and instead of ":myString" I will put "apple" it's working as intendent.

My guess it should be formatted differently as my other query with searching id by Int is working just fine.

@Edit:

I did read stack and I do have everything in Gradle that was recommended in other answers here :(

Comment: `Room` does not support this kind of query. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240906/android-room-order-by-not-working