# How can I make the query simply by passing paramter when I use Room in Android

Tags: android, android-room

I use Room framework in an Android Studio project.

At present, I need to get the records of MVoice and sort the query result by `createdDate desc`, `createdDate asc`, `name desc` or `name asc`.

So I write the following code, but it's too complex, I think maybe it can be simple, such as passing field as paramter, I don't know how to do, could you tell me?

**Code**

```
interface DBVoiceDao{      
   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY createdDate desc")
   fun listVoiceDateDesc():LiveData<List<MVoice>>


   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY createdDate asc")
   fun listVoiceDateAsc():LiveData<List<MVoice>>

   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY name desc")
   fun listVoiceNameDesc():LiveData<List<MVoice>>

   @Query("SELECT * FROM voice_table ORDER BY name asc")
   fun listVoiceNameAsc():LiveData<List<MVoice>>    
}      

data class MVoice(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,
    var name:          String = "",
    var path:          String = "",
    var createdDate:   Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),
    var isStar:        Boolean = false,
    var description:   String = "",
    var translation:   String = ""  
): Parcelable {}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` dose not support dynamically parameter, but you can achieve it by `@RawQuery`, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44240906/9629748) can help you fave further information. The link has provide some examples, so I would not post as an answer.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/adc8b7e67b1e05d7bc9ac6247b82cfa93a43a26f/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/database/GameDao.kt#L17) of me doing a `RawQuery` based on various filtering options.